# Windows Phone 8.1 set source of MediaElement

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, mediaelement

I would like to change the source of a Media Element in Windows Phone 8.1.
What i have done:
xaml.cs file:

```
MediaPlayer.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/song1.mp3", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
MediaPlayer.Play();
```

And my MainPage.xaml file:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="MediaPlayer" Source="Assets/song1.mp3" AutoPlay="False"/>
```

The ting is that i want to change the source and then play the new source file.
But when i press the button te execute the above code the song does not play, nothing happens. And i'm sure i have the right file path.

Comment: Are you using SL8.1 or WinRT API ?